# Почему Sql Server использует Index Seek при LIKE '%'+@Param+'%'?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Немного не понимаю логику:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему Sql Server выбрал поиск в индексе вместо того, что бы сканировать его? Хинтов нету.

Ведь используется оператор `LIKE` + еще с обоих сторон `%` стоят.

Если убрать параметр, то используется Index Scan, как и предполагалось => дело в параметре.

Я изучил вот [эту](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/optimize-for-unknown-sql-server-parameter-sniffing/) статью, где пишется, что когда используется параметр, то он генерит наиболее общий план.

Неужели SQL Server не может это за ранее увидеть `%` и сделать оптимальный план?

Вот я весь анонимизированный запрос и план выкладываю:

```
Declare Variable1 Nvarchar(255)='815'
;WITH Object1 AS (SELECT Object2.Column1,Object2.Column2 from Schema1.Object3 Object2
WHERE Object2.Column3 LIKE '%' + Variable1  + '%')
SELECT Object4.Column1 AS Column4,MAX(Object4.Column1) AS Column5,MIN(Object4.Column2) AS Column6,COUNT(Object4.Column2) AS Column7 
FROM Object1 Object4
GROUP BY Object4.Column1
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если указать хинт на FORCESCAN, то запрос выполняется шустрее 3 сек вместо 14 сек.

**UPD**

Если воспользоваться, то показывает такую картину `set statistics io, time on`:

Без FORCESCAN

> (затронуто строк: 6407) Table 'Folder'. Scan count 1, logical reads
>   274975, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob
>   physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. Table 'Worktable'. Scan
>   count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob
>   logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. Table
>   'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0,
>   read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob
>   read-ahead reads 0.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 14789 ms,  elapsed time =
>   14778 ms. Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other
>   SET operation.

И с:

> (затронуто строк: 6407) Table 'Folder'. Scan count 13, logical reads
>   278746, physical reads 2, read-ahead reads 2, lob logical reads 0, lob
>   physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. Table 'Worktable'. Scan
>   count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob
>   logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 28906 ms,  elapsed time =
>   2837 ms. Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other
>   SET operation.

Выполнял несколько раз на с одним и тем же параметром=> данные все в кеше.

Comment: Посмотрите что из себя представляют Expr1013 и Expr1014, оптимизатор может отсечь из диапазона NULL-значения или значения, у которых длина меньше, чем длина переменной @Str и тп

Comment: @DenisRubashkin ну переменная имеет значение '815', а скалары- это скорее всего COUNT,MAX,MIN, которые используются в выборке.

Comment: Тут почитайте [How can LIKE '%…' seek on an index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065994/how-can-like-seek-on-an-index). общая идея такова, что этот Seek по сути своей является Scan-ом по вычисленному функциями LikeRangeStart, LikeRangeEnd диапазону. А уж насколько эффективно этот диапазон вычисляется одному MS ведомо.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin тем не менее, с хинтом на INDEXSCAN шустрее работает...

Comment: У вас на картинке estimated plan? Покажите actual, для обоих запросов.

Comment: План с forcescan, насколько я понимаю, скорее всего практически такой же, только вместо _Nested Loops_ (и всего, что до него) сразу стоит _Index Scan_ (причём параллельный). И видимо параллельный scan выигрывает последовательный range scan.

Comment: @i-one да, вы правы на счет параллельного скана. Однако, все равно не понимаю, почему эти планы не сводятся к одному виду...

Comment: @PashaPash а он такой же, но с параллельным сканом индекса и без вложенного цикла.

Comment: @i-one в таблице 8774369 строчек. Актуально 16 000, ожидаемо 400 000. Это на операторе вложенного цикла смотрю.

Comment: Хорошо бы это в текст вопроса добавить тоже. Попробуйте с recompile, либо с другим индексом (см. ответ). Группировка по *storage_id*, я правильно понимаю? Зачем, спрашивается, было анонимизировать...

Answer (score 1):

> Почему Sql Server выбрал поиск в индексе вместо того, чтобы
>   сканировать его?

Дело здесь в сочетании двух факторов:

1. наличие индекса, в котором нужный для поиска столбец является
   ключевым и лидирующим
2. использование в качестве шаблона поиска функции `LIKE` скалярного
   выражения с участием переменной

Если вы уверены, что поиск по индексу вам не пригодится, то указание `FORCESCAN` - одно из возможных решений, но в данном случае, вероятно, не самое лучшее. Дело в том, что в плане запроса есть оператор *Sort*. И если, как вы пишете, на операторе *Nested Loops* у вас

> Актуально 16 000, ожидаемо 400 000.

(оптимизатор переоценил количество строк), то скорее всего для выполнения запроса выделяется избыточное количество памяти. Попробуйте добавить `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` к запросу, тогда оптимизатор сможет использовать сканирование, плюс оценка (и выделение памяти) станут, возможно, адекватнее.

Либо, если существующий индекс не используется для других целей, то вообще создать вместо него

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Folder_Storage_id ON [Folder] ([Storage_id])
    INCLUDE ([paths], [Name]);
```

тогда оптимизатор будет использовать сканирование индекса, как вы и хотите, плюс из плана запроса пропадёт сортировка.

Ниже некоторые подробности.

---

Возьмём из исходного запроса самое интересное

```
DECLARE @pattern nvarchar(255) = '815';

SELECT [Name]
FROM [Folder]
WHERE [Name] LIKE '%' + @pattern + '%';
```

Действительный план такого запроса выглядит следующим образом:

[image: 01]

```
|--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([Expr1007], [Expr1008], [Expr1009]))
   |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1007]=LikeRangeStart(N'%'+[@pattern]+N'%'),
   |    |                    [Expr1008]=LikeRangeEnd(N'%'+[@pattern]+N'%'),
   |    |                    [Expr1009]=LikeRangeInfo(N'%'+[@pattern]+N'%')))
   |    |--Constant Scan
   |
   |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([Simple].[dbo].[Folder].[IX_Folder_Name])
                 SEEK:([Simple].[dbo].[Folder].[Name] > [Expr1007]
                   AND [Simple].[dbo].[Folder].[Name] < [Expr1008])
                 WHERE:([Simple].[dbo].[Folder].[Name] like N'%'+[@pattern]+N'%')
                 ORDERED FORWARD)
```

т.е. SqlServer выполняет поиск, локализуя его в области, границы которой определяются динамически с помощью внутренних функций *LikeRangeStart* и *LikeRangeEnd*. Поиск в индексе по диапазону ключевых значений фактически является частичным сканированием (часто так и говорят *partial scan* или *range scan*).

Такой шаблон является специальным. Операторы *Constan Scan*, *Compute Scalar* и *Nested Loops* являются дополнительными и добавляются на этапе пост-оптимизационного преобразования (т.н. *post-optimization rewrite*). Этот шаблон (и другие ему подобные) хорошо описан [здесь](https://www.sql.kiwi/2012/01/dynamic-seeks-and-hidden-implicit-conversions.html). К тому, что можно найти в статье по ссылке хотелось бы, применительно к данному случаю, добавить следующее.

При использовании локальных переменных оптимизатор может прибегать к упрощённым оценкам селективности предикатов (см. [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/dd535534(v=sql.100)#avoid-use-of-local-variables-in-queries), раздел *Avoid use of local variables in queries*).

Так, например, на тестовой таблице

```
CREATE TABLE [Folder] ([Name] nvarchar(260) NOT NULL, [Filler] binary(400));
```

содержащей 100 тыс. строк

```
WITH Nums(N) AS (
    SELECT TOP (100000) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID)
    FROM sys.all_columns a, sys.all_columns b
)
INSERT INTO [Folder] WITH (TABLOCKX) ([Name])
SELECT
    REPLICATE(CONVERT(nvarchar(200), CAST(N AS binary(4)), 2), 25)
FROM Nums;
```

с индексом на столбце *Name*

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Folder_Name ON [Folder] ([Name]);
```

запрос вернул мне следующие метрики и оценки производительности:

[image: 02]

разбег оценочного количества строк с действительным составил более двух порядков.

Если посмотреть (с помощью флага трассировки 2363) источник этой оценки, то можно увидеть

```
Plan for computation:
  CSelCalcFixedFilter (0.09)

Selectivity: 0.09

Stats collection generated: 
  CStCollFilter(ID=2, CARD=9000)
      CStCollBaseTable(ID=1, CARD=100000 TBL: Folder)
```

что для расчёта селективности используется калькулятор *CSelCalcFixedFilter* (т.е. оценка селективности в данном случае есть величина постоянная). Использование табличной подсказки `FORCESCAN` на метод расчёта оценки не влияет, оставляя селективность постоянной равной 9% от общего количества строк в таблице.

Ещё один негативный момент заключается в том, что в этом шаблоне оператор поиска в индексе, по-видимому, не может быть параллельным. Если заставить оптимизатор генерировать параллельный план, то получается довольно бесполезная конструкция

[image: 03]

Впрочем, если бы даже оператор *Index Seek* в этом плане и мог быть параллельным, то выгода от этого была бы сомнительна, т.к. с параллелизмом на внутренней (*inner*) стороне *Nested Loops* есть определённые проблемы (см. [здесь](https://www.sql.kiwi/2011/12/forcing-a-parallel-query-execution-plan.html), раздел *A Note about Parallel Nested Loops*).

Возьмём теперь тот же самый запрос, но предикат будет не с переменной, а с литералом:

```
SELECT [Name]
FROM [Folder]
WHERE [Name] LIKE '%815%';
```

Действительный план запроса получился такой:

[image: 04]

```
|--Index Scan(OBJECT:([Simple].[dbo].[Folder].[IX_Folder_Name]),
              WHERE:([Simple].[dbo].[Folder].[Name] like N'%815%'))
```

у меня он не параллельный, т.к. строк в таблице не много, но в данном случае всё примитивно и никаких препятствий для параллелизма нет. Интереснее, впрочем, оценочное количество строк

[image: 05]

в сравнении с действительным количеством это уже величины одного порядка.

Если посмотреть источник этой оценки, то можно увидеть

```
Plan for computation:
  CSelCalcTrieBased
      Column: QCOL: [Simple].[dbo].[Folder].Name

Selectivity: 0.000107411

Stats collection generated: 
  CStCollFilter(ID=2, CARD=10.7411)
      CStCollBaseTable(ID=1, CARD=100000 TBL: Folder)
```

что она не фиксированная, а рассчитана с помощью *CSelCalcTrieBased* (калькулятор селективности на основе [префиксного дерева](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE)).

Представленные выше результаты получены на SqlServer 2014. В SqlServer 2008 оценка для предиката `LIKE` с литералом получилась (после `UPDATE STATISTICS ... WITH FULLSCAN`) идентичной

[image: 06]

А оценка для предиката с переменной получилась похожей

[image: 07]

но всё же несколько отличающейся, что ожидаемо, т.к. *Cardinality Estimator* в SqlServer 2014 претерпел изменения (отличия могут быть даже в минорных версиях одного релиза).

Флаг трассировки 2363 появился лишь в SqlServer 2014, поэтому в SqlServer 2008 нет возможности так же легко посмотреть источники оценок селективности. Некоторую информацию, впрочем, можно добыть с помощью отладчика.

Судя по стеку вызовов, в SqlServer 2008 для оценки селективности фильтра `LIKE` с литералом так же используется префиксное дерево (*CTrieInMem*):

```
(call-stack)
sqlservr!OptimizerUtil::ProbLikeGuess
sqlservr!CTrieInMemCore::UlCountLikeStrings
sqlservr!CTrieInMemCore::FFilterLike+0x2af
sqlservr!CTrieInMem::FFilterLike+0x2e
sqlservr!CInMemHistogram::FFilterLike+0x5d
sqlservr!CScaOp_Intrinsic::FCalcSelectivity+0x47c0
sqlservr!CalculateFilter+0x72
sqlservr!CSelContext::CalculateSelectivity+0x37e
sqlservr!GroupCard+0x736
sqlservr!CLogOp_Select::DeriveCardinality+0x587
...
```

а для для оценки селективности фильтра `LIKE` с переменной используется какое-то предположение (*ProbLikeGuess*)

```
(call-stack)
sqlservr!OptimizerUtil::ProbLikeGuess
sqlservr!CScaOp_Intrinsic::FCalcSelectivity+0x6023
sqlservr!CalculateFilter+0x72
sqlservr!CSelContext::CalculateSelectivity+0x37e
sqlservr!GroupCard+0x736
sqlservr!CLogOp_Select::DeriveCardinality+0x587
...
```

по-видимому на основе вектора плотности

```
(call-tree)
sqlservr!CLogOp_Select::DeriveCardinality+0x587
sqlservr!GroupCard+0x736
sqlservr!CSelContext::CalculateSelectivity+0x37e
sqlservr!CalculateFilter+0x72
  sqlservr!CScaOp_Intrinsic::FCalcSelectivity+0x34b
    sqlservr!CScaOp_Identifier::FCalcSelectivity+0x44a
      sqlservr!CInMemHistogram::CardGetStepTotal
    sqlservr!CScaOp_Identifier::FCalcSelectivity+0x47a
      sqlservr!CDensityGroup::FFindDensityByPvr
...
```

---

Резмируем вышесказанное. Неадекватные оценки могут быть причиной генерации неоптимального плана запроса, медленного его выполнения и/или избыточного выделения ресурсов. Если производительность запроса не устраивает, и причина низкой производительности именно в неадекватности оценок, то (в общем случае) можно попытаться это исправить следующими способами:

- обновить статистики на таблицах, участвующих в запросе
- добавить к запросу `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` (на тяжёлых запросах с
  несложным планом чаще всего это приемлемый компромисс)
- материализовать часть запроса в `#`-таблицу